# #Value! error with =(A1+A2)

Tags: sum

I'm trying to add multiple cells with the formula =(A1+A2+A3...etc)
Which works, but if all the cells are empty then I get a #Value!

PLEASE NOTE:
Yes I am aware the proper way to add cell values is with =SUM(A1:A3)
However the cells I'm adding together each have their own functions to get their numbers, and the =SUM function won't add them together.

So! Is there a way I can make =(A1+A2+A3...etc) not give me a #Value! error in the cell that's supposed to total them if ALL the cells (A1,A2,etc) are empty? (as in, the cell with the total will just be blank)

Yes I know this is overly complicated. I'm working with that I've got.

**EDIT**
I might have figured out my problem. My 'false' statement in the function of the cells that were being added is "" in order to make the cell not have a 0 in it when empty. When it tries to add those cells together, if they all read "" and none are a number that's when I get the #Value! error. Not sure yet what I'm going to do about that...

**EDIT 2**
Yup. Problem was caused by having a non-numerical value as my false statement. Didn't want a bunch of zeros everywhere, but oh well I guess.

Answer (score 1):

I tried both Excel 2007 and Calc 3.4.1, and neither one of these generated the #Value! that you mention.  I am thinking that perhaps your source cells' equations are producing a value that is causing this to error out.

For example, if one of the cells has a String value, then this will be the result.  This can be detected with the TYPE() function.  for example:

```
=( IF(TYPE(A1)=1;A1;0) + IF(TYPE(A1)=1;B1;0) + ...)
```

this will make sure that you are actually adding numbers before the addition takes place.

**edit**

See: http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/type.php
for details on TYPE()